# Is it possible to keep an instance on Node.js across an entire app?

Tags: node.js

I want to instantiate a class in a module like this:

```
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: mongoConnectionString}});
```

and then access the `agenda` already configured object from everywhere else in the code (like a singleton). At first I thought about using `module.exports = agenda;` but then when I require this module in another module of the application it will execute all the code again right?

So, if I'm not wrong which is the best approach to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: "but then when I require this module in another module of the application it will execute all the code again right?" -> nope

Answer (score 1):

You can use global object to share variables everywhere in your node application:

```
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: mongoConnectionString}});

global.agenda = agenda;
```

And then you can get your agenda in another module like this:

```
const agenda = global.agenda;
```

Comment: Yes I know, but this is an anti-pattern and a very bad practice. I'm looking for another options.

Comment: There is a great article explain [how to create a true singleton pattern in nodejs](https://derickbailey.com/2016/03/09/creating-a-true-singleton-in-node-js-with-es6-symbols/)